# mysql lost data rows after reboot

Tags: mysql, apache, ubuntu

I have an ubuntu server. 
I checked the server and I notice that had only 700mb of free hdd space so I restarted. I lost a few days of data in mysql and also I was unable to run apache and I had to installed apache again.

The hard disk now have a lot of free space.

Any of you know what can happen?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry this is far to vague a question. There are far too many *possible* answers. We can at best give uninformed guesses. You should not be loosing *days of* MySQL data in a reboot as data is (usually) stored on disc.

Comment: This is an admin/db management question. Try asking it on http://dba.stackexchange.com. Stackoverflow is for programming questions, not admin ones.